# Call PHP form from HTML

Tags: html, forms, php

**contact-form.html**

```
<form method="POST" name="contactform" action="contact-form-handler.php"> 
<p>
<label for='name'>Your Name:</label> <br>
<input type="text" name="name">
</p>
<p>
<label for='email'>Email Address:</label> <br>
<input type="text" name="email"> <br>
</p>
<p>
<label for='message'>Message:</label> <br>
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>
```

**contact-form-handler.php**

```
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'net.dev@spikyarc.net';
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
empty($_POST['email']) || 
empty($_POST['message']))
{
   $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

if (!preg_match(
  "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
$to = $myemail; 
$email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".


$headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//redirect to the 'thank you' page
header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
  } 
?>
```

This both file i have put in wwwroot folder but when i submit html form it gives error `The page cannot be displayed`. I cannot find problem. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Change your action to `action="contact-form-handler.php"`

Comment: change form action , action="contact-form-handler.php" ?

Comment: I have Change the action but it still gives the error..

Comment: check header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html'); page exist ?

Comment: Check your PHP log to see if it's getting errors.

Comment: change: action="contact-form-handler.php"

Comment: @Bora yes i get same error

Comment: tell the Addres (in Ad bar) contact-form.html  and the Address of  The page cannot be displayed ?

Answer (score 0):

set the action in the HTML form to:

`contact-form-handler.php`

like:

```
<form method="POST" name="contactform" action="contact-form-handler.php">
```

**UPDATE 1: And check this:**

Change

```
$email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
```

to

```
$email_subject = "Contact form submission:" . $name;
```

**UPDATE 2: And this also:**

```
$headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
```

to:

```
$headers = "From: " . $myemail . "\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To:" . $email_address;
```

**UPDATE 3:**

You validate the E-mail address `$email_address` but never use it.

Comment: No its still not working..I want to inform you that i have put the files in `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot`

Comment: No..i get same error with `The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because the page address is incorrect`

Comment: Is this path, the path to your webserver's (like apache) `www` directory?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37229/discussion-between-prashant16-and-q0re)

Comment: Yes..sry by mistake i closed the chat window

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check the filename with that in the action!!